# :target Pseudo Class Not Working in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, css

I'm trying to do the modal window out of pure HTML5 and CSS3. The code seems to work just fine in my JSFiddle, but isn't working at all in WordPress.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jesserogers/9so69d6x/3/

Code:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.featureModal {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(7, 57, 113, 0.75);
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.featureModal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.featureModal > div {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}
.closeModal {
  background: #0860b8;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.closeModal:hover {
  background: #073971;
}
.blockityblock {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.blockityblock > a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 35px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockityblock">
  <a href="#netboostModal">NetBoost</a>
</div>
<div class="blockityblock">
  <a href="#flowequalizerModal">Flow Equalizer</a>
</div>
<div class="blockityblock">
  <a href="#policypushModal">Policy Push</a>
</div>
<div id="netboostModal" class="featureModal">
  <div>
    <a href="#closeModal" class="closeModal" title="Close">x</a>
    <h2>NetBoost</h2>
    <p>The OneSite NetBoost feature ensures network responsiveness so applications and end users perform at peak productivity. Unlike TCP-based protocols, OneSite’s enterprise-grade, packet-level driver moves content at the highest possible speed while keeping
      latency low. Admins can specify the responsiveness threshold in milliseconds. OneSite keeps the network as snappy as you like, even when delivering large payloads over slow and poor connections.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="flowequalizerModal" class="featureModal">
  <div>
    <a href="#closeModal" class="closeModal" title="Close">x</a>
    <h2>Flow Equalizer</h2>
    <p>OneSite’s Flow Equalizer technology protects the WAN by proactively leveling out traffic when multiple downloads occur at once. Other technologies create a separate network flow for each download, and the multiple flows can overload the WAN—leading
      to speed-killing throttling. OneSite “time slices” many downloads into a single network flow that never spikes or impacts the network, safely delivering content at maximum speed with no throttling.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="policypushModal" class="featureModal">
  <div>
    <a href="#closeModal" class="closeModal" title="Close">x</a>
    <h2>Policy Push</h2>
    <p>OneSite’s Policy Push feature uses intelligence to deploy software instantly, instead of waiting up to an hour or more with native ConfigMgr and other solutions. This policy push mechanism delivers instructions to clients immediately, instead of waiting
      for the “polling” cycle, ensuring that all software updates happen rapidly. Simply set up your content distribution policies and let OneSite set them in motion instantly.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code snippet is slightly dumbed down, but the :target and modal functionality is exactly the same.

**My main question is, has anyone had any problems in WordPress with this kind of code?**

Comment: Make sure your css code is not clashing with other css files.

Comment: @SESN Nope, zero conflicts. In the actual implementation, unique class names and id's were used.

Comment: Can you share the URL of your site?

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian I'm just trying to get this one link to generate a modal window here on our staging environment: http://adaptiva.staging.wpengine.com/onesite

See the link "NetBoost" under the little blue line at the bottom of the first section.

Comment: Note that when you inspect the link, underneath it in the HTML, you can see the <div id="netboostModal" class="featureModal"> and its contents. If you change the CSS in the Google Dev Tools to "opacity: 1;" it shows up. Somehow, the :target function just isn't registering.

Comment: @rnevius Seems that way, yeah. I have tried changing all the IDs and class names to something randomized, but still no luck. I may have to bring in a more advanced dev consultant to find the problem if it's deep inside some other stylesheet. It's just weird that only the :target pseudo-class is giving me problems.

Comment: One issue I see on your staging site is that you have multiple elements with an ID of `netboostModal`. Not sure if that's causing the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You have multiple elements on the page which have the same ID of `netboostModal`.
2. The following JavaScript `click` event listener is blocking the execution of your modal:

   ```
   $("area[href*=\\#],a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#]):not([href^='\\#tab']):not([href^='\\#quicktab']):not([href^='\\#pane'])").click(function() {
       if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
           var target = $(this.hash);
           target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
               $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: target.offset().top - 0  
               },1000 ,'easeInOutSine');
               return false;
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's the JS that's the problem, since the modal didn't work before I'd put the second instance of `netboostModal`. I'm horrible at JS though, so I'll have to bring in a more advanced dev. Thanks! I'll be sure to award the answer if/when that is identified as the source of the problem.

Comment: The developer I contacted was able to pinpoint the plugin that was causing this based off the JS snippet you identified. Disabled the plugin, and my modal window immediately started working. Thank you!